# how to Add Permission Policy Level in web application with "Deny All" permission for Edit items using power shell script in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

how to Add Permission Policy Level in web application using power shell script and how I can assign the "Deny All" permission for Edit items using power shell script in SharePoint 2010.!

Answer (score 1):

Deny all permissions is not needed, if you select the permission level as read it will not let anyone to edit the item

`Set-SPUser -Identity 'domain\name' -Web http://www.test.com  -AddPermissionLevel Read`

Still if you want to add permission policy , this is the script

`$webapp = Get-SPWebApplication "http://www.test.com"

    $name = "Deny all"
$description = "Cannot edit items"
$policy=$webapp.policyRoles.Add($name, $description)
$policy.DenyRightMask="ViewFormPages,ViewVersions" //customize this according to your req.
$policy.GrantRightMask="ViewListItems, OpenItems, Viewpages, ViewUsageData"
$webapp.Update()`

reference: [http://books.google.com/books?id=rTBgroiWAesC&pg=PA251&lpg=PA251&dq=%22$wa.policyroles%22&source=bl&ots=mH5JbVRrYI&sig=hKMcVNqVgZyB5ZXvtb19-PaobCk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mFKjUff0MsqzygGOuoDAAQ&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22%24wa.policyroles%22&f=false](http://books.google.com/books?id=rTBgroiWAesC&pg=PA251&lpg=PA251&dq=%22%24wa.policyroles%22&source=bl&ots=mH5JbVRrYI&sig=hKMcVNqVgZyB5ZXvtb19-PaobCk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mFKjUff0MsqzygGOuoDAAQ&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22%24wa.policyroles%22&f=false)

Comment: Maybe you missed a 's' when you set property GrantRightsMask.